# how to format cake php radio button label

Tags: cakephp-1.3

hi i am  working on cake php.I created a radio buttons the code is

```
<?php echo $form->radio('ElemType', array('M'=>'Male','F'=>'Female'),
array('class'=>'inputType', 'legend'=>false));?>
```

It dispalys radio buttons my problem is it is maintain much space between radio button and 
  label.Please give me sugg to remove space

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean the line gap between label and radio button?
Well its simple, use this,

```
    <?php echo $this->Form->input('ElemType', array('type' =>'radio', 'option'=>('M'=>'Male', 'F' =>'Female'), 'legend' => false, 'div' => false)); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

To modify the display of these labels, you could use a surrounding div

```
echo '<div class="inline_labels">';
echo $this->Form->radio('ElemType', $options, $attributes);
echo '</div>';
```

and use CSS like this:

```
.inline_labels label
{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: He should use the internal "legend" parameter rather than adding a surrounding div, since Cake's FormHelper will anyway add a div by default and keep its default order if you do not change that through the `legend` and `div` `$options` params.

Answer (score 0):

This will surely solve the problem of Cake users

```
  <style type="text/css">
    input[type=radio] {
       margin:3px;
       width:23px;
    }

    .locRad {
         margin:3px 0px 0px 3px; 
         float:none;
    }
    </style>

<label>Select Payment Type</label>
<?php
$attributes=array('legend'=>false, 'label'=>false, 'value'=>'US', 'class'=>'locRad validate[required]');

echo $form->radio('Payment.type',array('M'=>'Male','F'=>'Female'),$attributes);
             ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple, you only need use attribute 'separator'

```
example:
<?php  
 $options=array('M'=>'Male'."<br>" , 'F'=>'Female');          
 $attributes=array('legend'=>false,'label'=>'gender_male.','class'=>'radio', 'div' => false, 'separator' => '&nbsp;&nbsp;');
 echo $this->Form->radio('gender',$options, $attributes);
?>
```